# How to fix EOF Error when reading a file using with open()

Tags: python-3.x, eof

I am making a program to read something from a group of files, but I get an EOF error.

```
def readMem(memId):

    with open(memId, "r") as rf:
        memVal = memId.read()
```

I get the error at the `with open()`, (error persists even without the last line) but I cannot find out why. In my knowledge, there is no issue, I have even used this EXACT code in a different file.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in a REPL, but I do get another error when trying to invoke `read()` on a `str`, should you be reading off of `rf` instead?

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut Yes I should have, as stated by an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the `read` method of the file object `rf` instead:

```
def readMem(memId):
    with open(memId, "r") as rf:
        memVal = rf.read()
```